# Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class,com.google.android.gms.location.LocationService

Tags: android, gradle, google-play-services

I'm getting an error when I run this line of code:

```
 mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
```

I think the error is caused by some misconfiguration in ProGuard, but I cant figure out what. Fyi, multidex is enabled.

If it matters, my app uses Firebase.

The app runs fine, but only crashes when the activity is started with the mGoogleApiClient.

The error is:

```
06-12 16:58:33.620 24826-24826/com.glennruysschaert.arbitrium I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices$zza>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzzv$zza;
06-12 16:58:33.620 24826-24826/com.glennruysschaert.arbitrium I/art:     at void com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices.<clinit>() ((null):-1)
06-12 16:58:33.620 24826-24826/com.glennruysschaert.arbitrium I/art:     at void com.glennruysschaert.arbitrium.Foursquare.FoursquarePlacePickerActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (FoursquarePlacePickerActivity.java:81)
06-12 16:58:33.620 24826-24826/com.glennruysschaert.arbitrium I/art:     at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:6760)
06-12 16:58:33.620 24826-24826/com.glennruysschaert.arbitrium I/art:     at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1134)
06-12 16:58:33.620 24826-24826/com.glennruysschaert.arbitrium I/art:     at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2681)
06-12 16:58:33.620 24826-24826/com.glennruysschaert.arbitrium I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2814)
06-12 16:58:33.620 24826-24826/com.glennruysschaert.arbitrium I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
06-12 16:58:33.620 24826-24826/com.glennruysschaert.arbitrium I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1527)
06-12 16:58:33.620 24826-24826/com.glennruysschaert.arbitrium I/art:     at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:102)
06-12 16:58:33.620 24826-24826/com.glennruysschaert.arbitrium I/art:     at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:154)
06-12 16:58:33.620 24826-24826/com.glennruysschaert.arbitrium I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6290)
06-12 16:58:33.620 24826-24826/com.glennruysschaert.arbitrium I/art:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
06-12 16:58:33.620 24826-24826/com.glennruysschaert.arbitrium I/art:     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (ZygoteInit.java:886)
06-12 16:58:33.620 24826-24826/com.glennruysschaert.arbitrium I/art:     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:776)
06-12 16:58:33.620 24826-24826/com.glennruysschaert.arbitrium I/art: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.internal.zzzv$zza" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.glennruysschaert.arbitrium-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.glennruysschaert.arbitrium-2/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
06-12 16:58:33.620 24826-24826/com.glennruysschaert.arbitrium I/art:     at java.lang.Class dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(java.lang.String) (BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
06-12 16:58:33.620 24826-24826/com.glennruysschaert.arbitrium I/art:     at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:380)
06-12 16:58:33.620 24826-24826/com.glennruysschaert.arbitrium I/art:     at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
06-12 16:58:33.620 24826-24826/com.glennruysschaert.arbitrium I/art:     at void com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices.<clinit>() ((null):-1)
06-12 16:58:33.620 24826-24826/com.glennruysschaert.arbitrium I/art:     at void com.glennruysschaert.arbitrium.Foursquare.FoursquarePlacePickerActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (FoursquarePlacePickerActivity.java:81)
06-12 16:58:33.620 24826-24826/com.glennruysschaert.arbitrium I/art:     at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:6760)
06-12 16:58:33.620 24826-24826/com.glennruysschaert.arbitrium I/art:     at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1134)
06-12 16:58:33.620 24826-24826/com.glennruysschaert.arbitrium I/art:     at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2681)
06-12 16:58:33.620 24826-24826/com.glennruysschaert.arbitrium I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2814)
06-12 16:58:33.620 24826-24826/com.glennruysschaert.arbitrium I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
06-12 16:58:33.620 24826-24826/com.glennruysschaert.arbitrium I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1527)
06-12 16:58:33.620 24826-24826/com.glennruysschaert.arbitrium I/art:     at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:102)
06-12 16:58:33.620 24826-24826/com.glennruysschaert.arbitrium I/art:     at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:154)
06-12 16:58:33.620 24826-24826/com.glennruysschaert.arbitrium I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6290)
06-12 16:58:33.620 24826-24826/com.glennruysschaert.arbitrium I/art:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
06-12 16:58:33.620 24826-24826/com.glennruysschaert.arbitrium I/art:     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (ZygoteInit.java:886)
06-12 16:58:33.620 24826-24826/com.glennruysschaert.arbitrium I/art:     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:776)
06-12 16:58:33.621 24826-24826/com.glennruysschaert.arbitrium I/art: Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.google.android.gms.internal.zzarl$zza>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/location/LocationServices$zza;
06-12 16:58:33.621 24826-24826/com.glennruysschaert.arbitrium I/art:     at void com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices.<clinit>() ((null):-1)
06-12 16:58:33.621 24826-24826/com.glennruysschaert.arbitrium I/art:     at void com.glennruysschaert.arbitrium.Foursquare.FoursquarePlacePickerActivity.onCreate(android.os.Bundle) (FoursquarePlacePickerActivity.java:81)
06-12 16:58:33.621 24826-24826/com.glennruysschaert.arbitrium I/art:     at void android.app.Activity.performCreate(android.os.Bundle) (Activity.java:6760)
06-12 16:58:33.621 24826-24826/com.glennruysschaert.arbitrium I/art:     at void android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(android.app.Activity, android.os.Bundle) (Instrumentation.java:1134)
06-12 16:58:33.621 24826-24826/com.glennruysschaert.arbitrium I/art:     at android.app.Activity android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent) (ActivityThread.java:2681)
06-12 16:58:33.621 24826-24826/com.glennruysschaert.arbitrium I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:2814)
06-12 16:58:33.621 24826-24826/com.glennruysschaert.arbitrium I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(android.app.ActivityThread, android.app.ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, android.content.Intent, java.lang.String) (ActivityThread.java:-1)
06-12 16:58:33.621 24826-24826/com.glennruysschaert.arbitrium I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(android.os.Message) (ActivityThread.java:1527)
06-12 16:58:33.621 24826-24826/com.glennruysschaert.arbitrium I/art:     at void android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(android.os.Message) (Handler.java:102)
06-12 16:58:33.621 24826-24826/com.glennruysschaert.arbitrium I/art:     at void android.os.Looper.loop() (Looper.java:154)
06-12 16:58:33.621 24826-24826/com.glennruysschaert.arbitrium I/art:     at void android.app.ActivityThread.main(java.lang.String[]) (ActivityThread.java:6290)
06-12 16:58:33.621 24826-24826/com.glennruysschaert.arbitrium I/art:     at java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke!(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[]) (Method.java:-2)
06-12 16:58:33.621 24826-24826/com.glennruysschaert.arbitrium I/art:     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() (ZygoteInit.java:886)
06-12 16:58:33.621 24826-24826/com.glennruysschaert.arbitrium I/art:     at void com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(java.lang.String[]) (ZygoteInit.java:776)
06-12 16:58:33.621 24826-24826/com.glennruysschaert.arbitrium I/art: Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices$zza
06-12 16:58:33.621 24826-24826/com.glennruysschaert.arbitrium I/art:     at java.lang.Class java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass!(java.lang.ClassLoader, java.lang.String) (VMClassLoader.java:-2)
06-12 16:58:33.621 24826-24826/com.glennruysschaert.arbitrium I/art:     at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:742)
06-12 16:58:33.621 24826-24826/com.glennruysschaert.arbitrium I/art:     at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String, boolean) (ClassLoader.java:362)
06-12 16:58:33.621 24826-24826/com.glennruysschaert.arbitrium I/art:     at java.lang.Class java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(java.lang.String) (ClassLoader.java:312)
06-12 16:58:33.621 24826-24826/com.glennruysschaert.arbitrium I/art:     at void com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices.<clinit>() ((null):-1)
```

My ProGuard file:

```
-keep public class * implements com.bumptech.glide.module.GlideModule
-keep public enum com.bumptech.glide.load.resource.bitmap.ImageHeaderParser$** {
  **[] $VALUES;
  public *;
}

-dontwarn okio.**
-dontwarn javax.annotation.**

-keep class com.google.android.gms.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
```

Gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "MYAPPID..."
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled  true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha9'
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    //Firebase
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.0.0'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:1.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:9.2.0'

    //Circle Image
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'

    //Glide - Offline image store library
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0-RC0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.0.0-RC0'

    //Info dialog: https://github.com/yarolegovich/LovelyDialog
    compile 'com.yarolegovich:lovely-dialog:1.0.7'

    //Calendar like transition between activities: compile 'com.kogitune:pre-lollipop-activity-transition:1.x.x'
    compile 'com.kogitune:pre-lollipop-activity-transition:1.3.3'


    //Control animations: https://github.com/andkulikov/transitions-everywhere
    compile "com.andkulikov:transitionseverywhere:1.7.4"

    //Http requests: https://github.com/square/retrofit

    //Play services
    //compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.0.1'

    //Multidex
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

The libs folder only contains: retrofit-2.3.0.jar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out. I seems to be due to conflicting Google Play Services versions.

I used the following command to check the Play Services dependencies of Firebase:

```
gradle app:dependencies
```

That showed that Firebase was using an older version than I was.
So I set the Firebase version to 11.0.0 and removed 'firebase-analytics'. Then I also set the maps and location version to 11.0.0 and check the dependencies again with the command.

Now all dependencies of Google Play Services were the same. Now the app runs fine.